# Angular 6: How to Intergarte calender/date picker with form?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have two divs one contain a date picker /calender which allow user to select a date they want, second contain the form with email, citym and hotel,

so a user select a date and fill the form and submit it by clicking book.

Here is what I have

```
<div class="container about-booking-input">
  <div class="row about-title">
    <div class="col-md-7 about-title_bookingtitle">
      <h2>Booking</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row about-booking">
    <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 about-booking_calendar">
        <app-calendar></app-calendar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 about-booking_form">
      <flash-messages></flash-messages>
      <form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-element">
        <div class="form-group form-element_email">
          <input type="email" class="form-control info" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" #email (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['email'].dirty || angForm.controls['email'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].errors.required">
            Email is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_city">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #cityName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.name">{{city.name}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_hotel">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #hotelName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.name">{{hotel.name}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" (click)="addReview(email.value, cityName.value , hotelName.value)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-element_btn"
            [disabled]="!validEmail">Book</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Visul the looks liek this.
[image]

Right now I can submit just form without a date, after googling and googling found nothing helpful,

Note: I am using this datepicker ui : ignite -ui angular https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/calendar.html

> Question

How do I intergrate my calender with  form and be able to  submit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have to make your `app-calender` component become a custom form control. One nice article about this: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

In a nut shell, your `AppCalenderComponent` has to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface to be able to communicate with the `formGroup`. After you have successfully implemented the `ControlValueAccessor` for your `AppCalenderComponent`, you can include it in the form like below:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-calendar formControlName="nameOfTheDatePickerControl"></app-calendar>
</form>
```

Comment: Hii, I have created as you advised me but am getting error , here is my new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210526/angular-6-proper-implementation-of-controlvalueaccessor